# Autodesk Forge Viewer load multiple model

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I follow this article to create load assets function:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-models-viewer

But i have problem about viewer performance, for few models it alright, but when i load many models, viewer rerender all time and not stable, video below (If i load all family in revit first then translate later, it works normal). I already set `skipPropertyDb:true` in `options` when load sub Model, all models are `svf2`. Are there any settings or solutions to keep it works? Something like clone model in scene or just load only geometry to viewer?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxOwz_UatZw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewer is optimized for rendering **fewer** models that are potentially **very complex**. If you go the other way around (rendering **more** models that are relatively **simple**), you'll miss out on many of the performance optimizations.

To work around this issue, you could try one of the following:

- include the additional models in the "main" model, and hide/show them (and move them around) as needed
- simplify the additional models you're inserting into the scene